# MySql WHERE IN (SELECT + HAVING) or search multiple joined rows using WHERE AND

Tags: mysql, join

,Is it possible to tell MySql not to return a column that I need to generate in order to use HAVING?

```
SELECT * 

---other joins

FROM programs

WHERE id IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT keywords.name SEPARATOR ", ") AS keywords_names
    FROM programs

    LEFT JOIN program_keywords pk ON pk.program_id = programs.id
    LEFT JOIN keywords ON keywords.id = pk.keyword_id

    ---other joins

    WHERE ---

    HAVING keywords_names LIKE '%keyword1%' AND keywords_names LIKE '%keyword2%'

)

GROUP BY programs.id

ORDER BY programs.name, programs.id ASC
```

As you can see  keywords_names will generate an error because the WHERE IN expects one column.

Ideally instead of HAVING, I could use

```
WHERE keywords_names LIKE '%keyword1%' AND keywords_names LIKE '%keyword2%'
```

but this doesn't work as none of the returned rows have both keywords even if the rest of the data is the same.

I need to find programs that have both keywords attached to them.

My next attempt will be to separate the queries into 2 separate ones, extract the ids in an array and use that one in the second query, but this will not be as efficient probably.

**EDIT:**
I guess the question comes down to how do I achieve

```
HAVING keywords_names LIKE '%keyword1%' AND keywords_names LIKE '%keyword2%'
```

with JOINS

Thank you

Comment: Read MySQL documentation.  Learn the syntax.

Comment: does it look like I don't know some of the syntax?

Comment: If you knew the syntax, you would know not to put `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: But I know why it doesn't work, and only added the above here so you can see what I am trying to achieve.